# How can I make a text area look exactly the same as a div element?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, textarea

I need to make a `textarea` and a `div` look exactly the same in all browsers.

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/eric777/XHtY9/

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I presume you're asking how to have a `div` look like a `textarea`, as a `div` as standard is just an empty container. Are you also aware that `textarea`s look different in different browsers?

Comment: 1. What should they look like? 2. Use a CSS-reset to get rid of the browsers default styling, then apply the styling you want.

Comment: here is quick example - http://jsfiddle.net/XHtY9/14/

Comment: If you are trying to make a `<div>` appear editable, then you might be able to use the `contenteditible` attribute: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable/

Answer (score 3):

First, I believe that forcing something to look exactly the same in all browsers is an approach that is about to die out. It is much easier to embrace the differences and let inputs etc. vary slightly in style between browsers. Very few visitors will visit your site will multiple browsers anyway, so very few will even notice the difference.

Now on to answer your actual question. Since you haven't specified what the textarea/div should look like, I cannot provide you with a complete set of properties, but here is an approach to how to achieve it.

1. Use a CSS-reset, [like this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (there are others as well), to get rid of the default styling applied by each browser. Now the page start of with the same look in all browsers.
2. Apply your desired styling on both the div and the textarea.
3. A textarea will scroll by default when the content does not fit. You might have to fake that for the `div` element using `overflow-y: scroll;`.